# Proof of sum of subspaces and decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_0$ be the vector space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $W_0 = \{f \in V_0 : f(0) = f(1) = 0\}$. We also denote $\mathbb{R}_1[X]$ a subspace of $W_0$ of polynomial functions.

I want to prove that $W_0$ and $\mathbb{R}_1$ are complementary subspaces.

Let $f \in W_0 \cap \mathbb{R}_1[X]$. Since f(0) = 0, we have $f(x) = ax + b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Since f(1) = 0, we have $a+ b = 0$. This means that $f$ must be the zero polynomial since otherwise it would not satisfy $f(0) = 0$. Therefore $W_0 \cap \mathbb{R}_1[X] = \{0\}$

I can't find a decomposition of $V_0$ in $W_0$ and $\mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be any continuous function. We want to write $f(x)=ax+b+g(x)$ with $g \in W_0$. $x=0$ gives $f(0)=b$ and $x=1$ gives $f(1)=a+b$. So we must have $a=f(1)-f(0)$ and $b=f(0)$. Now go backwards:  With this choice of $a$ and $b$ define $g(x)=f(x)-ax-b$ and check that $g \in W_0$ so that  $f(x)=ax+b+g(x)$ is the required decomposition.